# Codeigniter cannot fount from action url

Tags: php, codeigniter

First, the code its working on localhost but when I try to deploy it  on a remote server,the url are nor found
I have set the domain name on /etc/hosts

```
serverip myfakedomain.com
```

At the remote server I can see the main page , but when I try to log in ,submiting a form  I get this message `The requested URL /Login/checkLogin was not found on this server.`

this is the form

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <?php echo form_open('Login/checkLogin'); ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo form_label('Usuario:'); ?>
            <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'username', 'name' => 'username', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>"Nombre de usuario")); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo form_label('Contraseña:'); ?>
            <?php echo form_password(array('id' => 'pass', 'name' => 'pass', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>"Contraseña")); ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Enviar', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary')); ?>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
```

this is te controller/function not  an url

```
<?php echo form_open('Login/checkLogin'); ?>
```

but the forms submit request its done on

```
myfakeDomain.com/Login/checkLogin
```

and there is no such url,I repeat on localhost woks.

Comment: Do you use base_url() and .htaccess file?

Comment: @SamirJana I've set the base_url , and I set the htacces to remove the index.php from the url, do I have to do something else?

Comment: PHP is the case sensitive, so check the root to controller path and with all function name and folder name, I hope you have mistake uppercase/lowercase letter.

Comment: Its not a case problem

Comment: at your production server: is your rewrite_module loaded in httpd.conf (this line: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`)? One just can guess to answer, because you don't show any details of your config

Comment: @Vickel the server has other codeigniter projects working, its sure that has the rewritemodule on

Answer (score 0):

try to change the base_url in config file to your host

Comment: it's changed with the smae domain  as is set the /etc/hosts file

Comment: do your write your controller a capital  letters or other use folder inside controller folder must have a first litter is capital  --- and check your htaccess file under rewrite base /